# In Oracle ERP cloud how to get deeper details of Roles which includes Function Security Policies,DataSecurityPolicies,RoleHierarchy of particular Role

Tags: oracle, oraclereports, fusion, oracle-ebs, oracle-fusion-apps

We are doing lot of analysis around this but not getting solution for this requirement

Basically we want to fetch deeper details of Roles which includes Function Security Policies, Data Security Policies, Role Hierarchy of particular Role

Theses details we are easily getting from Oracle ERP Cloud UI in Security Console but we want to fetch these details from Rest/Soap API due to some of our business needs

We found one API which works great but gives us only basic info of Role

```
/hcmRestApi/scim/Roles/
```

Is there any way to get these details, this is becoming roadblock for us to use Oracle ERP cloud.

Thanks In Advance..!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SCIM REST API you cannot get the function security policies, data security policies and role hierarchy of particular role but by running the "User And Role Access Audit Report" you can View all roles, privileges, and data security

You would have to run "Import User and Role Application Security Data process" to get data populated before running the "user and role access audit report"

**So we have to go via Reporting**